# I'm trying to iterate through an array list, find the first item in the array in which the boolean is false, set it to true and return it

Tags: java, if-statement, for-loop, arraylist, boolean

this is my method to add a taxi driver

```
public class TaxiController {

ArrayList TaxiList = new ArrayList();

public void addTaxi(String cabNumber, String driver, boolean booked){
    //add a taxi to the taxi list
    Taxi deltaTaxis = new Taxi(cabNumber, driver, booked);
    TaxiList.add(deltaTaxis);

}
```

this is my for loop, attempting to iterate through the array list, find the first false boolean and set it to true

```
public void bookTaxi(){
    //book a taxi
    for (int i = 0; i < TaxiList.size(); i++){
        if (i == false) {
            (i == true);
        }
        return (i);
    }

}


public class KwikTaxi {
    //name taxi company
    TaxiController delta;

    public KwikTaxi(){
    //add taxis to the taxi queue, set booked to false as default
    addTaxis();

}
```

here i've added a few items into the array and set them to false by default

```
public void addTaxis(){
    delta = new TaxiController();

    delta.addTaxi("001", "John", false);
    delta.addTaxi("002", "Pete", false);
    delta.addTaxi("003", "Chris", false);
    delta.addTaxi("004", "Will", false);
    delta.addTaxi("005", "Emma", false);
    delta.addTaxi("006", "Joe", false);
    delta.addTaxi("007", "Rhys", false);
    delta.addTaxi("008", "Colm", false);
    delta.addTaxi("009", "Steve", false);
    delta.addTaxi("010", "Matthew", false);

}
}
```

Comment: i think you mean `if(!TaxiList.isBooked())` instead of `if (i == false)`, since `i` is an `int`

Comment: You are attempting to compare an int to a boolean and return an int from a method with a void return type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everyone for your help. This is the solution I came up with that also worked

```
public void bookTaxi(String isTaxi){
    //book a taxi
    Taxi getTaxi;
    String nowGetTaxi;
    for (int i = 0; i < taxiList.size(); i++) 
    {
        getTaxi = taxiList.get(i);
        nowGetTaxi = getTaxi.getNo();

        if (isTaxi.equals(nowGetTaxi)) 
        {
            getTaxi.setbooked(true);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you don't understand how looping through a collection works. The variable `i` is an integer used as an index, and thus can never be neither `true` nor `false`.

General remarks:

- In java, the convention is that classes start with a capital letter, variable do not.
- The convention for using collections is to type the variable as an `interface`
- Your `void` method can't `return` anything
- Lists and other collections should be parameterized, so you can tell what type of object it can contain.
- When a variable is of the type `List`, repeating this information in the variable name is uneccessary
- Comments that just states what is obvious are generally uneccessary
- For-each loops are nice

Then, your code should look something like:

```
public class TaxiController {

    List<Taxi> taxis = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addTaxi(String cabNumber, String driver, boolean booked) {
        taxis.add(new Taxi(cabNumber, driver, booked));
    }

    public void bookTaxi(){
        final Taxi taxi = findAvailableTaxi();
        if (taxi != null) {
            taxi.book();
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException("No available taxis!");
        }
    }

    private Taxi findAvailableTaxi() {
        for (final Taxi taxi : taxis) {
            if (!taxi.isOccupied()) {
                return taxi;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: As Tobb do not know how your Taxi class looks like, his taxi.isOccupied() should return the booked boolean.
Tobb, shouldn't bookTaxi return the taxi itself? I guess this depends on exactly how OP wants it.

Comment: I dont know if he has such a method, but as it would be fairly simple to deduce what such a method would do I took my chances. Whether or not bookTaxi should return a Taxi is hard to know, since it originally was a void method that returned something. I chose to hide the internal workings of booking a taxi behind a book()-method..

Comment: First comment was for OP. Sorry. Second comment, same as your thinking as I said this depends how OP exactly wants it. He wasn't too clear on it, as he said he want the taxi to be returned but his method is void. Then again, he's trying to use for loop counter to compare to his taxi boolean. Hard to tell what he wants. So meh...

Comment: Yeah, saw that after I posted, but didn't make that much difference that I bothered editing :) a bit hard to say, tried to repeat as little as possible of what I considered poor code design from the OP..

Answer (score 0):

First, you are trying to compare an `int` with a `boolean`.

To do it:

```
public Taxi bookTaxi(){
    // book a taxi
    for( int i = 0; i < TaxiList.size(); i++ ){
        Taxi taxi = TaxiList.get( i );
        if( !taxi.isBooked() ){
            taxi.setBooked( true );
            return taxi;
        }
    }

    throw new IllegalStateException( "Unexpected situation" );
}
```

You don't have to throw an exception, instead you can check if your array really contains at least one or more taxis.

Don't forget to add `getters` and `setters` to your bean.